# Android when to upload to server

Tags: android, upload

I have an application that stores the user's interest kind of like StumbleUpon. I present the user's interest to them in an List Activity. If they decide to change an interest, when should I upload the changes?

Should I upload after the change, so when a checkbox changes, or should I upload in bulk after they exit out of the activity?

EDIT: 
I have other data that takes the user's interest, so having the most accurate representation of the user's interest is very important. And because there is an accompanying website that the user is also able to change interests, I need to take into consideration which changes take precedence. So I need something speedy, but I also don't want to kill the user's battery.

Comment: Isn't there anything like SAVE button (or) so? There are lot of cases you may need to consider. Let us say if user checked box, then clicked back, in this cases AFAIK, no activity will be called, so you may loose selected data (if you wait for bulk save). More information will get you correct answer.

Comment: @thinksteep: No matter what the case, you could always detect the activity exiting and save the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating for each checkbox would be more accurate, but updating in bulk would be more battery-friendly. Either way, you should make sure you are doing the uploads asynchronously, as to not block the UI.

I assume that the ListActivity to change interests is a sort of preference screen? If so, then under normal conditions, a user wouldn't need their interests to update immediately after they check a box. They would only need them to update before the next time they use them. The transition from the preferences screen back to the main activity should give enough time for the updates to push to the server.

Comment: But what if the data needs to stay in sync with a server?

Comment: @Hank: Maybe I misunderstood your setup. Is the page to change interests in the android app, or somewhere else?

Comment: The page allows changing of interests, but there is also a web site that allows you to change the same interests

Comment: Okay, but as I said in my answer, the user won't need the updated interests until they go to use them, which I assume wouldn't happen until they exited the preference screen? Same goes for the web page - generally you hit a "Save" button or something for a list of checkboxes on a web page. So you could still save them in bulk, and they would be saved before the user needed them.